# Adding a current_password field to the following change password view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an **User** model that I built using Rails's `has_secure_password` (based on the [Rails tutorial Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)):

**schema.rb:**

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "password_digest"
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :avatar, :password, :password_confirmation, :provider, :uid

  has_secure_password

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

And I have a view like this `uses/password_edit.html.erb`:

```
<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password, "New Password" %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Retype Password" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

Now, I want to add a `:current_password` field on the top. The problem is that the database only has a `password_digest` column.

So, I'm a bit lost here. I'm not even sure how to make the form throw an error when the `current_password` is incorrect.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

**users_controller.html.erb:**

def update
    old_password = params[:current_password]

```
if authenticated = User.authenticate(old_password)
  if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
    # Use old password if none indicated
    params[:user][:password] = old_password
    params[:user][:password_confirmation] = old_password
  end
end

@user = User.find(params[:id]) 
@user.errors.add(:base, "Invalid password") unless authenticated
@user.updating_password = true if params[:form_name] == "edit_password"
if authenticated && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to @user
else
  if params[:form_name] == "edit_password"
    render 'edit_password'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
@user.updating_password = nil
```

end

Comment: Can you add what your view looks like now and fix the formatting on your controller edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar recently. I added an input in my view that wasn't associated with the model, and then my controller looked like this:

```
def update
  old_password = params[:current_password]

  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if authenticated = @user.authenticate(old_password)
    if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
      # Use old password if none indicated
      params[:user][:password] = old_password
      params[:user][:password_confirmation] = old_password
    end
  end

  @user.errors.add(:base, "Invalid password") unless authenticated

  if authenticated && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  ...
end
```

It seemed to work for me. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Oops, this would discard any changes from the user if they failed to authenticate. I can modify it to include that if you want or leave it as an exercise for the Questioner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you include that please?

Comment: Sure thing. I think you can just add the following two statements before the last line `@user.assign_attributes(params[:user])` and `@user.valid?` then you can change the last line to `@user.save`.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this associate with the `:current_password` field? Right now the `:password` and `:current_password` fields are OK (they create and confirm a new password). I just need to create the `:current_password` field.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't use your names originally.

Comment: strange, I'm getting `undefined method `authenticate' for #<Class:0xa144da8>` (I posted the whole controller please see my EDIT). But the way, shouldn't password or current_password be a new password instead of the old one?

Comment: I don't think your formatting worked correctly in your edit. I set the current password to the old password in case they didn't enter a new password. That way I wouldn't accidentally clear their password. If your controller is just for updating their password then you can remove that section of my code.

Comment: But strange, only this works: `@user.authenticate(old_password)` I suppose is the same? But when I enter the old password in `current_password` it says invalid password.

Comment: Oh goodness gracious! I'm sorry I copy pasted and tried to adapt to your example but messed that up. I edited again.

Comment: Thanks! It works but if I enter the current password I still get the invalid error. Maybe I have to do `params[:user][:current_password]` instead? but then I get the mass assignment error and if I add it to the `attr_accesible` I get `unknown attribute: current_password`.

Comment: Hey it worked after I did this: `params[:user][:current_password]` `attr_accesible :current_password attr_accesor: current_pasword.` Strange. Thanks! I still didn't understand this part thought: `@user.assign_attributes(params[:user]) and @user.valid?` Do I have to put them in an if statement? Could you update your code with it?

Comment: If you are only updating the password, they are unnecessary. I was updating all fields in my model including (optionally) the password.